# What is the role of an intermediate fix?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts

There are the IAF and the FAF, which has clear roles. One is where you start the approach and the other where you start to descent and end the approach. But what is the purpose of an Intermediate fix?[image]

Comment: How is IAF, the Intermediate Approach Fix, different than "Intermediate fix"?  Do you have a chart example showing both?  I think that there are approaches where the IAF is overflown at one altitude outbound, then one circles back and descends inbound to cross the same point as the FAF.

Comment: The IAF is meant to be the Initial Approach Fix. Or am i wrong? Please do correct me. Added a picture.

Comment: Oh, that's right, "Initial" Approach Fix. I am out of practice!  As the chart shows, the IF is between the IAF and the FAF, and is a tracking/reporting point after the holding pattern. Might be a mandatory reporting point, or you may be asked to report when getting there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an explanation that I read and I liked the most as I think it better explains the *role* of the intermediate segment and thus the intermediate fix. Skybrary in the [IAP page](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Instrument_Approach_Procedure_(IAP)) mentions:

> Intermediate approach segment - this segment usually begins at the intermediate fix (IF) and ends at the final approach fix (FAF) or final approach point (FAP). **Here the aircraft speed and configuration should be adjusted to prepare for the final approach. For this reason, the descent gradient is kept as shallow as possible.**

Emphasis is mine as up until that point there is nothing new. Checking the ICAO Doc 8168 PANS-OPS cited by Skybrary, in `Chapter 4 INTERMEDIATE APPROACH SEGMENT` paragraph `4.1.1` we read that

> The intermediate approach segment blends the initial approach segment into the final approach segment. It is the segment in which aircraft configuration, speed, and positioning adjustments are made for entry into the final approach segment.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to all the elements in [JScarry's excellent answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/54707/167), intermediate fixes can also be used to step down altitudes, such as during the ILS 10C at Chicago O'Hare.

[image]

Comment: This is probably the most succinct answer to the OP’s question ie “what is the purpose of an IF?” as opposed to “what is an IF?”

Answer (score 3):

The [Pilot/Controller Glossary](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/pcg_10-12-17.pdf) can shed some light on your question.

The GPS approach is the clearest example of an Intermediate Approach Fix.

> IF/IAWP− Intermediate Fix/Initial Approach Way- point. The waypoint
>   where the final approach course of a T approach meets the crossbar of
>   the T. When designated (in conjunction with a TAA) this waypoint will
>   be used as an IAWP when approaching the airport from certain
>   directions, and as an IFWP when beginning the approach from another
>   IAWP.
>
> INTERMEDIATE APPROACH SEGMENT [ICAO]− That segment of an instrument
>   approach procedure between either the intermediate approach fix and
>   the final approach fix or point, or between the end of a reversal,
>   race track or dead reckoning track procedure and the final approach
>   fix or point, as appropriate.

The Instrument Flying Handbook warns that, “Randomly joining an approach at an intermediate fix does not ensure terrain clearance."

On other approaches, there may not be an intermediate fix, but the segment is defined as follows:

> INTERMEDIATE FIX− The fix that identifies the beginning of the
>   intermediate approach segment of an instrument approach procedure. The
>   fix is not normally identified on the instrument approach chart as an
>   intermediate fix (IF).
>
> INITIAL APPROACH SEGMENT [ICAO]− That segment of an instrument
>   approach procedure between the initial approach fix and the
>   intermediate approach fix or, where applicable, the final approach fix
>   or point.

The Instrument Flying Handbook also talks about intermediate fixes where there is sometimes a charted Intermediate Fix:

**Teardrop Procedure**

> When a teardrop procedure turn is depicted and a course reversal is
>   required, unless otherwise authorized by ATC, this type of procedure
>   must be executed. [Figure 1-15] The teardrop procedure consists of
>   departure from an IAF on the published outbound course followed by a
>   turn toward and intercepting the inbound course at or prior to the
>   intermediate fix or point. Its purpose is to permit an aircraft to
>   reverse direction and lose considerable altitude within reasonably
>   limited airspace. Where no fix is available to mark the beginning of
>   the intermediate segment, it shall be assumed to commence at a point
>   10 NM prior to the FAF. When the facility is located on the airport,
>   an aircraft is considered to be on final approach upon completion of
>   the penetration turn. However, the final approach segment begins on
>   the final approach course 10 NM from the facility.

**Holding in Lieu of Procedure Turn**

> A holding pattern in lieu of a procedure turn may be specified for
>   course reversal in some procedures.  In such cases, the holding
>   pattern is established over an intermediate fix (IF) or a FAF.