# Can IAF and IF be in the same spot?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

While looking over an ILS approach chart,
I found that there is a fix where says : (IF/IAF) ACZUP ...

And I was consfused whether the two IF and IAF can be in the same place, or the spot is used as IAF or IF in a certain occasion.

Could anyone tell me which is the right thing?

[image]

(IF = Intermediate Fix; IAF = Initial Approach Fix)

Comment: Related: [What is the role of an intermediate fix?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/54699/14897)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An IF is any fix between the IAF and FAF, so as a matter of logic, the same fix cannot be both an IAF and an IF *at the same time*. Therefore the label IAF/IF must mean it can be either one or, in some cases, both *at different times*.

If you are cleared to ACZUP for the straight-in approach, then ACZUP is the IAF only. You never pass it a second time, so it doesn't get a chance to be an IF.

If you are cleared to HABJE for the approach, then HABJE is the IAF and you do not pass over ACZUP, so it is neither IAF nor IF.

Otherwise, ACZUP is the IAF when you pass over it outbound, then you do the Hold in lieu of Procedure Turn (HiloPT), and then ACZUP is an IF when you pass over it again the second time inbound. The same would be true if it were charted as a PT instead of HiloPT.

In all three cases, MRVIN is the FAF due to the lightning bolt symbol.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Is that an aviation knowledge or is it mentioned in the chart?

Comment: And I want to know if there is NO intermediate fix in the straight in approach...

Comment: @ StephenS Okay, I got it. I was just confused because of the fact 'No Intermediate fix' can happen.

Comment: @Student412 I've incorporated my previous comment into the answer; let me know if it's still unclear.